# How to refer to Unsafe Browser in Tails OS using environment variable in .bashrc

Tags: configuration

I need to set a SageMath environment variable in .bashrc to use the Unsafe Browser to connect to localhost:8080 and use Sage's notebook interface (as far as I can tell, the Tor Browser can't view localhost).

The Sage example of setting the default browser as Firefox is to add 
export SAGE_BROWSER="firefox" 
to .bashrc

Trying

```
export SAGE_BROWSER="unsafe browser"
```

fails with a message that unsafe can't be found.

What should be in the " " to call the Unsafe Browser?

Comment: Probably the name of the browser, something like "firefox".

Answer (score 0):

The unsafe browser is run as a clearnet user with less restrictions in Tails, there is no seperate binary. So run the script as normal and "firefox -P /path/to/clearnet/user/profile" which should be in profiles folder in the firefox folder. Set that as the EXPORT and all should be well.